# How to make frame to expand when i make my Main Window fullscreen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

How can i make my frame to expand when i open my window on full screen? As you can see on pictures, when i make my window fullscreened, my frame don't want to expand. May you tell me how to fix it please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems like you're not using any [layout manager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event functions resizeEvent

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
       QWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)
       Width = self.frameGeometry().width()
       #set your frame with to the new width
```